# ValueError: Missing scheme in request url Scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

i am trying to scrape `https://www.skynewsarabia.com/` using `Scrapy` and i having this error `ValueError: Missing scheme in request url:` 
i tried every single solution i have found on stackoverflow and none worked for me. 
here is my spider:

```
name = 'skynews'
allowed_domains = ['www.skynewsarabia.com']
start_urls = ['https://www.skynewsarabia.com/sport/latest-news-%D8%A2%D8%AE%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1']
}
    def parse(self, response):
    link = "https://www.skynewsarabia.com"
    # get the urls of each article
    urls = response.css("a.item-wrapper::attr(href)").extract()
    # for each article make a request to get the text of that article
    for url in urls:
        # get the info of that article using the parse_details function
        yield scrapy.Request(url=link +url, callback=self.parse_details)
    # go and get the link for the next article
    next_article = response.css("a.item-wrapper::attr(href)").extract_first()
    if next_article:
        # keep repeating the process until the bot visits all the links in the website!
        yield scrapy.Request(url=next_article, callback=self.parse)  # keep calling yourself!
```

here is the whole error:

```
2019-01-30 11:49:34 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)

2019-01-30 11:49:34 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-01-30 11:49:35 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.skynewsarabia.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2019-01-30 11:49:35 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.skynewsarabia.com/sport/latest-news-%D8%A2%D8%AE%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1> (referer: None)
2019-01-30 11:49:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.skynewsarabia.com/sport/latest-news-%D8%A2%D8%AE%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\hozrifai\desktop\scraping\venv\lib\site- 
      packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
      yield next(it)
     File "c:\users\hozrifai\desktop\scraping\venv\lib\site- 
    packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 30, in 
 process_spider_output
       for x in result:
      File "c:\users\hozrifai\desktop\scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 339, in <genexpr>
return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
File "c:\users\hozrifai\desktop\scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
File "c:\users\hozrifai\desktop\scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
File "C:\Users\HozRifai\Desktop\scraping\articles\articles\spiders\skynews.py", line 28, in parse
   yield scrapy.Request(url=next_article, callback=self.parse)  # keep calling yourself!
 File "c:\users\hozrifai\desktop\scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 25, in __init__
   self._set_url(url)
 File "c:\users\hozrifai\desktop\scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 62, in _set_url
   raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: /sport/1222754-%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%B1%D9%86%D9%84%D9%8A-%D9%8A%D8%B6%D8%B9-%D8%AD%D8%AF%D8%A7-%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%AA%D8%B5%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%B3%D9%88%D9%84%D8%B4%D8%A7%D8%B1
2019-01-30 11:49:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.skynewsarabia.com/sport/1222754-%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%B1%D9%86%D9%84%D9%8A-%D9%8A%D8%B6%D8%B9-%D8%AD%D8%AF%D8%A7-%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%AA%D8%B5%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%B3%D9%88%D9%84%D8%B4%D8%A7%D8%B1> (referer: https://www.skynewsarabia.com/sport/latest-news-%D8%A2%D8%AE%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you look at the value in the error message it's complaining about? It's a *relative* link, you need to prefix it to make it an absolute URL.

Comment: The value of `next_article` is relative URL (`/sport/1222754...`). You have to provide absolute URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `next_article` url without scheme. Try:

```
next_article = response.css("a.item-wrapper::attr(href)").get()
if next_article:
    yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_article))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your Next article retrieval:

```
next_article = response.css("a.item-wrapper::attr(href)").extract_first()
```

Are you sure you are getting full link starting from `http/https`?

For better approach if we are not sure about the url we are receiving always use `urljoin` as:

```
url = response.urljoin(next_article)     # you can also use this in your above logic.
```

Comment: this is why i have a `link` variable! and then i am adding it to the `relative url`

Comment: but you not adding it to next_article actually.